# apache spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using spark structured streaming to read incoming data from an s3 location, so i have 2 questions here.

Question 1)

I start my structured streaming pipeline which reads the incoming files in s3. I provide the schema for the incoming json data as

col A, col B, col C

I perform some transformations and write the data to another s3 location in parquet format which has the below schema

col A, col A', col B, col B', col C, col C'

Now say after some days my incoming streaming data changes and and so i need to change my incoming schema to

Case 1) col A, col B, col C, col D

Case 2) col A, col B

Then after i do the transformation i need my new transformed schema in parquet as

Case 1) col A, col A', col B, col B', col C, col C', col D, col D'

Case 2) col A, col A', col B, col B'

So is this thing possible considering the streaming output is written to a parquet file

Question 2)

Spark structured streaming uses checkpointLocation, so is there any way we can reprocess some/all precessed data.

Comment: For Question 1) 

It seems we could do something like this 

spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("s3...")

Answer (score -1):

Answer for your Question 2

Just delete the directory of checkPointing location & restart the process.

Comment: Yes but is there as way to reprocess some specific data,
deleting the checkPointing location will reprocess everything